# regex and getting slashes plus characters from a url

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, slash

Why doesnt this rule return slashes with characters?

```
RewriteRule ^test/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/?$ test.php?one=$1&two=$2&three=$3
```

For example in this URL

[mysite.com/test//one///two////three///](http://mysite.com/test//one///two////three///)

It'll return

```
$1='one' 

$2='two' 

$3='three'
```

But I want it to return

```
$1='/one' 

$2='//two' 

$3='///three///'
```

I also tried `^posts/{1}(.+)/{1}(.+)/{1}(.+)/?$` but it did't work too...

nothing else comes to my mind. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL may have been processed before by the server, removing double slashes. If you match the full URL, are all slashes still there?

Comment: thanks! I tried this regex `^test/(.*)$` for the previous URL and the output was `$1='one/two/three/'`. It seems apache removes multiple slashes without redirecting to corrected URL. I was trying to prevent duplicate content for my site but apache is making it much harder!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
RewriteRule ^test(/+[^/]+)(/+[^/]+)(/+[^/]+/*)$ test.php?one=$1&two=$2&three=$3
```

Comment: This regex is working great and for the previous URL (that apache changes automatically to `mysite.com/test/one/two/three/` result is `$1='/one' $2='/two' $3='/three/'` and It seems to work if apache doesn't remove multiple slashes!